# Batch get value using substring from a file with multiple line

Tags: batch-file

I have a file like this:

```
875462874    id1   name1   homeHH01      cityABC1
463816351    id2   name2   homeH2        cityAA2
983616131    id3   name3   homeI3        cityCC3
565462231    id4   name4   homeOeew4     cityCDADA4
```

The file name is myfile.txt

And I have an bat file:

```
   set "file=myfile.txt"
   for /f "delims=" %%x in (%file%) do set build=%%x
   set "one=%build:~2,8%"
   set "two=%build:~29,14%"
   set "three=%build:~43,20%"

   echo %one%;%two%;%three% >> output.txt
```

And the output only show firstline. Other lines not showing.

```
875462874;homeHH01      ;cityABC1
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify that `myfile.txt` has lines of strings each separated with multiple adjacent, but different numbers of, space characters. Can you please also confirm whether any of the strings themselves contain any space characters, and if so, whether they could contain any sequence of spaces. Also, you haven't asked a question, simply posting a task description, and code, does not indicate to us, a problem you would like us to assist with. Pease [Edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for respon. I've edited. Yes, each line can have different spacing. But the first letter in each value is always in the same position on each line. For example, the letter C in the city column is always in substring position 44.

Comment: I want the output based on the position of the substring not delimiter.

Comment: That's only answered part of my questions, and you were asked to make an [Edit] when doing so. Instead you've made an edit, but only to change theinput file content, and the wanted output format. That has also prompted another required clarification; so you want all the trailing spaces included with `%token2%` but no trailing spaces included with the other two variable values, is that correct? We also need you to clarify that the fixed width never changes, so for example, the fourth field/column can never be more that 14 characters long!

Comment: Oh I see, It would be nice if the value in token 2 does not contain spaces, so it will trim the spaces in the output.

Comment: And I need output like this, after trim spaces.

875462874;homeHH01;cityABC1
463816351;homeH2;cityAA2
983616131;homeI3;cityCC3
565462231;homeOeew4;cityCDADA4

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have not yet answered the questions I've asked? or indeed asked an on topic question yet yourself! I need the output like this or this does not tell us what the issue is with the code you have posted and what we can do to help you to fix it. Please remember that this site is not a code to order service, we only help you to fix a reproducible issue with your submitted code, which has already attempted the stated task.

Comment: You need to: **1.** Put a `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command at beginning. **2.**  Change `do set build=%%x` by `do (` and put `set build=%%x` in a line below it. **3.** Change all _single_ `%` percent chars by `!` exclamation marks. **4.** Insert a line with just a `)` below the `echo !one!;!two!;!three! >> output.txt` line